# How to install a clock or weather application with Gnome 3.8?

Tags: gnome, 13.04

So I installed gnome 3.8 onto my ubuntu 13.04 pc.
It all works pretty fine except for one scrolling problem I resolved.
(as a note, if anyone is having a problem where their scrolling no longer works after installing this, you can fix it in dconf for touchpad)

Anyway on to my question. The guide installed gnome shell but I am missing a few applications for it. such as the clock or weather app. 
I was wondering if anyone knew a way to install these, thanks.

I meant to include the guide I used, here it is: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/gnome-3-8-ppa-for-ubuntu-gnome

Comment: The clocks applications can be attained from `apt-get install gnome-clocks`

Comment: Also the weather app is 'gnome-weather' `apt-get install gnome-weather`

Answer (score 2):

Those apps haven't been installed because they are new apps in the repositories as apposed to updates. You can install them manually though.

Gnome Clocks is the package `gnome-clocks` and can be attained with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-clocks
```

Gnome Weather is the package `gnome-weather` and can be attained with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-weather
```

It probably isn't that hard to find the other new apps, if you have some idea of what they are called you can type it into apt-get install and press tab for auto-completes. For instance I found the weather app by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-w
```

and pressing tab.

Answer (score 0):

For the time, for some reason if you click on the battery icon there is a show clock option. that's how I made it show.

The proper way would be to go to System Settings and select 'Time and Date' then the Tab 'Clock', that should turn the clock on!

Comment: I was referring to the new applications and stuff (ex. they have a new notes app called Bijiben) They aren't really required but they seem cool. I had the time via a different clock app (the time was still up at the top via the older 3.6 clock app.. but I heard they came out with a couple new apps for the 3.8 release and was looking for those)

Comment: Sorry, you said clock in your question, so I started there :D

Comment: I Found and installed some of these apps by going to the gnome source for the package names and using the apt-get install command. this seems to have worked. But I am unsure wheather there are other packages that these apps depend on that I did not install.

Comment: I have been using Ubuntu for 3 weeks now, I'm sorry, but I don't know what's new.

Comment: Gnome 3.8 is not supported in any stable version of Ubuntu and you should know that if you add an untrusted and unsupported PPA may result in lot of problems.

Comment: I do know that, and i didn't have problems, i was just missing a few extra things. other then that the env. works fine.